# Bootstrap-Native with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-native

Since I don't want to use Bootstrap jquery or reactstrap, I'm trying to implement bootstrap native in react, a plain javascript version of bootstrap, in React.

tried

```
pm install --save bootstrap.native
```

and loaded with

```
import 'bootstrap.native/dist/bootstrap-native-v4.js';
```

But it does not work, I tried with the CDN before the closing body tag in index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap.native/2.0.27/bootstrap-native-v4.min.js"></script>
```

But functionalities like modals and dropdowns doesn't work, I have no error in the debug console.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not a duplicate of another problem with **bootstrap.native** but it has the same result so my answer is:

The reason modals and other elements are not shown is that bootstrap.native uses the browser DOM, which is going to wreck havoc with React's virtual DOM. In short: It does not work at all!

Use [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) it is a complete rewrite of bootstrap.js (and also no jQuery)
From the developers:

> React-Bootstrap replaces the Bootstrap JavaScript. Each component has
>   been built from scratch as a true React component, without unneeded
>   dependencies like jQuery